# Rails form not persisting data after update_attributes fails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following

```
@account = Account.find(4)
respond_to do |format|
 format.html { render :action => "edit" }
end
```

which render a form

```
<%= form_for(@account,:html => {:id => "account" }) do |f| %> 
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.label :amount %>
  <%= f.text_field :amount %>      
<% end %>
```

which sends an update to

```
@account = Account.find(params[:id])
@account.update_attributes(Account.params(params))
respond_to do |format|
 format.html { render :action => "edit" }
end
```

I have function in  Account model

```
def self.params(params)
    params.require(:account).permit!
end
```

When the account fails to update. 
I see the errors but the form does not persist the data I tried to update account with?
I tried using

```
<%= form_for(@account,:html => {:id => "account" }) do |f| %> 
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name, :value => params[:user][:name] %>
  <%= f.label :amount %>
  <%= f.text_field :amount, :value => params[:user][:amount]  %>      
<% end %>
```

but when I load the edit page those fail.

Thanks

Comment: I suppose you are using rails 4 or 5 and strong parameters are a must. Make sure the parameters are permitted. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Comment: not sure if this is a typo or copy paste error but I see an issue with your:  @account = Account.find(params[:id)  - you are missing the closing bracket after [:id

Comment: I have updated the code and still getting the same issue!
I tried adding the params in both Model and Controller and was still getting the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue that was happening was for one reason. The code was inheriting  from a class that had:

```
slef.reload
```

in one of the function that were being called during validations.

so every time we try to update the update failed because once that validation was hit it reloaded the original values from database and ignored new values which if old values are empty is just a head scratcher.
So when it came time to display the old values are gone.
Thanks everyone for the help